# Match bitwise operators in lex

Tags: regex, yacc, lex, regular-language

I am implementing the lexical and syntax analyzer for a c++ like programming language
I have the following line in the regular expressions' section in lex file

```
arithm_op       [/+*%-]
bitwise_op      [&^~|]
punctuators     [()=;{}]
```

For the following input in the parser file:

```
int a;
int c;
print(a|c);
```

The bitwise operator is not matched. The program terminates just before the lex file reaches the '|' symbol in the print statement

I have tried to escape the pipe '|' in the regex but didn't work yet.

Comment: You don't need to escape `|` inside `[]`.

Comment: Not reproducible -- include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)